# All apps moved onto the SD card have disappeared

Tags: applications, sd-card, lg-optimus-l5-2

On My phone LG E460, all the applications moved on SD card, have disappeared.

On play.google.com (and play store) these applications are marked as installed. 
I don't know how to reactive these applications.

The app advanced SD card doesn't see them.

Comment: Did you swap SDCards? Or delete the hidden directory `.android` which is where the apps and data are stored?

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the phone usually solve this problem for me. Alternatively remove your SD card and put it back...